# Proximity Sensor Switch Circuit

Tags: digital-logic, sensor, switches, comparator

My goal is to build a proximity sensor switch circuit that can turn an LED on OR off. If I wave my hand, the light will turn on. Similarly, the light will turn off if I wave my hand the second time. I understand about comparators and its relation to a proximity sensor circuit. I just would like to clarify about how I would use the logic output HIGH of that circuit to turn an LED on OR off.

Any idea would be appreciated.

Thank you very much.

Comment: You need to study flip flops and monostables to get a fuller idea on what you need to do. You also need to study the methods used to detect movement. You have given no information as to your level of understanding of anything relevant. Adding this to your profile or the question would be useful.

Comment: Logic output high is your power supply to that logic gate. You can simply feed this output to an LED + resistor.

Comment: @MrPhooky how does that produce a latching circuit?

Comment: There are IC's such as max30105 (Adafruit sells a breakout board for it) that have this functionality built in. In your case you would use the _int_ pin to drive your LED. The range may not match what you have in mind - in any case you should update your post with the range spec.

Comment: @Andyaka That would be my mistake - my skim-reading is not what it used to be.

Comment: @Andy Can you see the circuit below and explain its working? TIA

Answer (score 1):

Feed your logic signal to the clock input of a flipflop, such as CD4013. On the 4013, connect D to /Q so it will toggle.

Q output with be your latched output.

This is just one way.. there are many other solutions.